# Illustrator - Import Graphic Style Library Via Script?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Is it possible to import a Graphic Style Library in Adobe Illustrator using Javascript?

I am creating a script to distribute to users.

The package contains 1 script and a graphic style library that is required to apply a crystalize effect in the script.

Is there a way to open the graphic style library from the script?

The script and library will both be located in the Adobe Illustrator Presets.

I am trying to reduce the amount of actions required by the user so that they only need to run the script without having to open the graphic style library first.

Comment: You can create template doc file with the necessary graphic style library and users will create own files from this template.

Comment: The script is intended to be used in their current file or project.

Comment: In this case you can create doc file with graphic style applied to some dummy object. From script open this file and copy this object to user project file ( it's necessary to copy graphic style) and then apply this style to user object.